# How to remove unicode from Graphql error message

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have a try and catch in my resolver and the catch looks like this

```
catch (err: any) {
            LOG.error("Failed to get location with ID: " + args.id);
            LOG.error(err);

            throw new Error(err);
        }
```

When I run a query in graphql the following error message appears

```
 {
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Error: \u001b[31m5 NOT_FOUND: Location was not found\u001b[39m",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 34,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getLocation"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "getLocation": null
  }
```

How do I remove the \u001b[31m5 from the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the console is not recognized Typescript.

```sh
$ npm install —dev @types/node
```

Did you install `@types/node` ?